# Issue with pushing data into firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Here I'm trying to push the data inside the array in Firebase, but it's pushing the data continuously until the cache from the app is destroyed. Here is my code and Firebase screenshot.

**code:**

```
 var Input = {
                AaMessage: 'brb',
            }
            var query = firebase.database().ref('UserList/');
            query
                .orderByChild('PostId')
                .equalTo(this.state.PostID)
                .on('value', snapshot => {
                    snapshot.forEach(child => {                      
                        firebase
                            .database()
                            .ref('UserList/' + child.key + '/Paymentdetails')
                            .push(Input)
                            .then(resp => {
                                console.log('Done', resp);
                            })
                            .catch(err => {
                                console.log('Error', err);
                            });
                    });
                });
```

**Firebase view:**

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to state what you expect your code to do instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're opening a listener which writes to the same node it listens to. Even if that's not causing recursion, you're still writing a new doc for every child every single time your UserList is updated.

Also, avoid mixing lists and documents in a single rt-db node. That can only lead to pain.

It's difficult to understand what you are trying to do -- but it looks like you might want to call `once` instead of `on`, so the listener doesn't stay open and keep writing (potential lots of) new documents.

Additionally, I would recommend not writing to the node you're listening to.
`database().ref("SomewhereElse/").push(doc);`

I don't know why you would want to push new docs whenever the snapshot updates, you're going to get a lot of duplicates. If that was a mistake you likely want to do those pushes in a `onCreate` trigger.